# How to prevent multiple users with same details being created simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, duplicates

I'm trying to create a signup form in PHP and it's working fine; the username and encrypted password and email are added to the database and if the username or email already exists then the user is notified that he cannot use these details. However; I have a curious bug, when I submit a user, two copies appear in my database.

I'm not sure how this can be the case as JavaScript is single threaded and so even if I was to spawn two AJAX requests the second one should fail as a user with that username would now exist?

How can I get around this problem?

I am using the following PHP file to handle the AJAX request:

```
// Get our user-data:
 $username = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : die( "You must enter a valid username" );
 $password = isset( $_POST['pass'] ) ? $_POST['pass'] : die( "You must enter a valid password" );
 $email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

 try {
     $connection = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server_name;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password );
     $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

     // Check to see if that username or password exist:
     $sql_statement = $connection->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1" );
     $sql_statement->execute( array( $username ) );
     if( $sql_statement->fetchColumn() > 0 )
     {
         // That username already exists:
         die( "That username already exists" );
     }

     $sql_statement = $connection->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `email` = ? LIMIT 1" );
     $sql_statement->execute( array( $email ) );
     if( $sql_statement->fetchColumn() > 0 )
     {
         // That email is already used:
         die( "There already exists an account under that email address" );
     }

     // Add the user to the database:
     $sql_statement = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO users( username, email, joined, password ) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?)" );
     $sql_statement->execute( array( $username, $email, password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT ) ) );
 }
 catch( PDOException $e )
 {
     die( "There was an internal database error whilst creating your user, error code (" . $e->getCode() . ")" );
 }
```

Comment: i just want to say im overjoyed you're using PDO, prepared statements, and correctly hashing your passwords. Well done. Also, in MySQL, make the email field a unique index and then see what errors get thrown where.

Comment: this has nothing to do with JS threads. JS doesn't enter in the picture. You're doing http requests from two different users. If their requests hit the server at the same time, they can BOTH run the exact same queries in parallel (remember, each http request is completely independent of every other one), get the same "this username is not used" response, and both do their inserts at the same time. Your code is inherently racy.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, that makes sense; how will I avoid this race condition though?

Comment: @castis Thank you; I am trying to ensure security as I go along! So I should just make username and password unique and then let the server (MySQL) do the uniqueness checking for me?

Comment: put a unique key on the username field. No matter how many people are submitting the same username at the same time, only ONE of them will actually get a successful insert, and the rest will fail with a duplicate key violation. detect that error and return the same "already exists" error for the unlucky people.

Comment: @MarcB You should add your comment as an answer: it solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

perhaps use sum instead of count, even make it unique field in the database, but for performance, it is more efficient to find the root cause why its entering ajax twice, is the form being submitted twice? if so you can perhaps avoid it by putting extra checks in if statement and can put breakpoints and printing out the values every variables